# What is the 'fillna()' euiqvalent for dtype 'Int32'?

Tags: python, pandas, nullable, fillna

Short question: How can I **set all values that are <1 or `<NA>`** to 1?

Long question: Say I have a pure-int (`int32`!) pandas column, I used can do this to cap the minimum:

```
>>> shots = pd.DataFrame([2, 0, 1], index=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], columns={'shots'}, dtype='int32')
shots
     shots
foo      2
bar      0
baz      1

>>> max(shots.loc['foo', 'shots'], 1)
2

>>> max(shots.loc['bar', 'shots'], 1)
1
```

So far, so good. Now, say the dtype of column `shots` changes from 'int32' to `Int32`, allowing `<NA>`. This gets me in trouble when accessing `<NA>` records. I get this error:

```
>>> shots = pd.DataFrame([2, np.nan, 1], index=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], columns={'shots'}, dtype='Int32')
     shots
foo      2
bar   <NA>
baz      1

>>> max(shots.loc['bar', 'shots'], 1)    
`TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous`
```

What should I do?

My first intuition was to say "Ok, let's fill  values, then apply max().". But that also fails:

```
>>> shots.loc[idx, 'shots'].fillna(1)

AttributeError: 'NAType' object has no attribute 'fillna'
```

--> What is the most pandiastic/pydantic way to apply a condition to `<NA>` values, i.e., setting all `<NA>` to 1, or applying some other form of basic match, such as `max(<NA>, 1)`?

Versions

- Python 3.8.6
- Pandas 1.2.3
- Numpy 1.19.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`idx` should be a collection else if it's a scalar you get a scalar value:

```
# idx = 'bar'

>>> shots.loc[idx, 'shots']
<NA>

>>> shots.loc[idx, 'shots'].fillna(1)
...
AttributeError: 'NAType' object has no attribute 'fillna'

>>> shots.loc[[idx], 'shots'].fillna(1)
bar    1
Name: shots, dtype: Int32
```

The question is how `idx` is defined?

---

**Old answer**

Your problem is not reproducible for me.

```
shots = pd.DataFrame({'shots': [2, 1, pd.NA]}, dtype=pd.Int32Dtype())
idx = [2]

>>> shots
   shots
0      2
1      1
2   <NA>

>>> shots.dtypes
shots    Int32
dtype: object

>>> shots.loc[idx, 'shots'].fillna(1)
2    1
Name: shots, dtype: Int32
```

Versions:

- Python 3.9.7
- Pandas 1.4.1
- Numpy 1.21.5

Comment: added an explicit, long code example above.. does that help you reproduce the error?

Comment: @KingOtto. I updated my answer can you check it please?

Comment: Do you understand where is the error now?

Comment: It does work! Now I got it, thanks! Of course you are calling the operation with `idx = [2]` (or ['foo']), to apply to a Series, not to the value! Thanks